# Openfire doesn't work with Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openfire

I wanted to add users to `openfire` from Rails app. I used this gem but the gem not valid now is there is any way to do this ?

It gives me this error:

> Could not find a valid gem 'https://github.com/paulasmuth/openfire_api.git' (>= 0) in any repository

https://github.com/paulasmuth/openfire_api

Comment: Can you show the entry in your gem file?  Did you follow the suggestions on the site?  `gem "mtgox-ruby", :git => "git://github.com/paulasmuth/openfire_api.git"`

Comment: yes this is my  entry file 
gem "mtgox-ruby", :git => "git://github.com/paulasmuth/openfire_api.git"
@Rustam

Comment: @Mostafahosny : did you found answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The gem you have mentioned, is only the client side for a plugin that can be used with openfire.

Both rails and openfire can be run together on any machine (though they should ideally run on separate instances), so they can be most definitely be used.

For adding/deleting/updating users, use the user plugin for open fire and make REST calls from your rails app.